# Pycharm community: how to revert to previous version (uninstall 3.0.2 patch which breaks Terminal plugin)

Tags: python, downgrade, community

Is there a way to undo pycharm patch installtion and downgrade from 3.0.2 to 3.0.0 ?

JetBrains web page under [previous versions](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/Previous+PyCharm+Releases)  shows only 2.X branch and it's not clear where to get original 3.0.0 install package for community version.

Packages for previous versions can be found by modifying direct download links

http://download-ln.jetbrains.com/python/pycharm-community-3.0.exe

and even 3.0 is there (not sure if JetBrains approves sniffing on their distrib server) but maybe downgrade can be done without re-installation?

Answer (score 0):

The update to Pycharm 2020.5 broke on my computer because it lacked space, so then my IDE was broken, I couldn't open the settings anymore.
I used this tool https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/, to install the latest version again, and delete the faulty one.